# Guiding a user into specific pages

Tags: navigation, menu

one of the unused features of the holiday package site I am working on is a country page.

the structure of the site currently goes:

```
URL > Country > Resort > Hotel
```

Currently the menu shows the countries as headers and resorts underneath these to help users who already know what they want. however I feel this may be overwhelming users who are looking to be 'helped into a decision'

The countries are currently shown as headers in the menu, alternatives suggested are a second tier navigation, so users have to manually hover over the country first. and a breadcrumb on the resort page so users can see that the country is a page itself.

Are there any other alternatives or ideas that could help guide users into this section of the site?

Comment: Small note: Remember not to rely too heavily on hover states since these are inaccessible to touch interface visitors.

Comment: yeah, the menu itself currently shows everything. so if we were to use a multi-level then i'd need to make a new 'mobile-only' interface too

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1  Input box: "What country would you like to visit?" Inputed text guides user to that country page?

2  Maybe there's an All Countries option, listing all countries maybe by region, featuring popular or hidden gem resorts (or any other criteria) on that All Countries landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think hiding information from users who know what they want, in the name of guiding some other users into a decision, would be a poor design choice.  Few things annoy users more than being guided through a process when they already know what they want.  Anyway, merely hiding one of the tiers doesn't really "guide", does it?  It just makes it harder to access the information.

I would suggest leaving all the information visible on the menu and have a separate way of accessing the information that is designed to guide users.  For example a "top resorts" feature or a search engine that allows you to select by characteristics (price, type of destination, etc.).

Comment: we already use a top resorts feature. If i'm honest I think the way that the resorts themselves are displayed is fine, its just actually getting people to view the whole country now, or atleast making it obvious that the country is a clickable link aswell as just a header

Comment: @LiamHT, perhaps you could use stylistic cues to make it clearer that the countries are clickable?